# XSLT template match and XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have XML file:

```
...
    <Chart id="c01">
      <expires>2012-07-19 12:20:00</expires>
      <data><![CDATA[...]]></data>
    </Chart>
...
```

where CDATA is B64 encoded PNG image, and whanted to transform XML to HTML to view the image.

For that purpose I set XSL to output text and dump CDATA:

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="//data/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

*In the same template I wrap basic HTML structure, which I excluded here for clearance.*

The problem is this: If I use XPath on XML file `//data/text()` I get just CDATA text, but with above XSL I get also "2012-07-19 12:20:00" from `<expires>` XML element, in the output.

I guess it's some basic thing I'm missing, but why is date also outputed and how can I avoid it in output?

Comment: I might be missing something here, but are you expecting to be able to transform the results of an encoded PNG image into the HTML, and then see that image displayed within the browser? If that is the case, I'm afraid you don't fully understand how images within HTML pages work

Comment: It is possible with `<img src="data:image/png;base64,($B64_data)/>`

Comment: You learn something new everyday... my apologies @theta, I will remove my answer immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably the shortest way to achieve this is**:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::data)]/text()"/>
```

**The complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::data)]/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the XML document**:

```
<t>
    <Chart id="c01">
        <expires>2012-07-19 12:20:00</expires>
        <data><![CDATA[ImageBlob]]></data>
    </Chart>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
ImageBlob
```

Comment: Thanks, I did `match="/"` and later either referencing `//data/text()` or `*[not(self::data)]/text()` for `xsl:value` worked fine. I had to use it like that because I had to wrap CDATA in HTML structure (with concat), and that is the only way I know in XSL currently, while probably there is a better one to this whole thing.

Comment: @theta: You are welcome. Do note that using `//` can be very inefficient and in most cases specific location steps are faster. Also, using "push style" processing and proper template match patterns it is often possible to avoid complex logic inside the body of templates.